# How to type-pun Boost quantity arrays to the underlying type?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, boost, undefined-behavior, type-punning

I'm building a dynamic animation & rendering system and I would like to use [Boost.Units](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/units/) for representing physical quantities to get the nice dimensional safety. However, I will have to pass arrays of quantities around to functions which know nothing about Boost, such as:

- OpenGL buffer-filling commands. These simply take a `const void *` and expect to find an array of either `float` or `double` values when dereferencing it. They read the data.
- Linear algebra functions (such as `gemm` or `gesv`) from different implementations of BLAS and LAPACK. These generally take either a `float *` or `double *` to a given array. They both read and write to the data.

I know that `boost::units::quantity<U, T>` has a `const T& value()` member which gives direct reference access to the contained `T` value. I have also verified that a `boost::units::quantity<U, T>` is a standard-layout struct with exactly one non-static data member, of type `T`.

So, let's assume that for a `boost::units::quantity<U, T> q`, the following holds:

- `static_cast<const void*>(&q) == static_cast<const void*>(&q.value())`
- `sizeof(q) == sizeof(T)`

**My question is**: given an array `boost::units::quantity<U, T> a[100];`, is it safe to:

1. Pass `&a[0].value()` to a function which expects to read an array of 100 objects of type `T` at the address?
2. Pass `reinterpret_cast<T*>(&a[0])` to a function which will write 100 sequential values of type `T` at the address?

I am well aware this is probably Undefined Behaviour, but right now I have to follow the "Practicality beats purity"<sup>(1)</sup> principle. Even if this is UB, is it one which will do the expected thing, or will it bite in unforeseen ways? Since this might be compiler-specific: I need this for modern MSVC (from VS 2015).

And if this is not safe, is there a way to actually do this safely? With "this" referring to "using Boost.Units with OpenGL and with number crunchers which only have a C interface," *without* unnecessarily copying data.

---

<sup>(1)</sup> Adapted from the [Zen of Python](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/).

Comment: I think where you say UB you mean IB? Because no one should ever shrug off UB.

Comment: Ironically, these functions end up in what is basically a void* interface. So decisions about aliasing were made already when those external libraries were compiled. So you really can choose where to establish your aliasing rules if any which ultimately are ignored by the binary executable. What c++ is lacking is a good method to express this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this looks like something you can do.

There's one thing you didn't mention and should be added to the list of conditions to check, though: the alignment of the wrapped amount type should match that of the underlying type. (see [**`alignof`**](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/alignof)).

So, in practice I'd write code like this only with a number of static_asserts¹ that guard the assumptions that make the re-interpretation valid.

If you add the assertion that T is the same as `remove_cv_t<decltype(q.value())>` this should be reliable.

With these pre-cautions in place there should not be UB, just IB (implementation defined behaviour) due the semantics of reinterpret_cast on your particular platform.

¹ and perhaps the debug assert that `&q.value() == &q`

Comment: But violating the strict aliasing rule is UB, not IB. (It's violated in the functions called, that is, BLAS/LAPACK/OpenGL C code violates it.)

Comment: Mmm. There's that aspect. I don't know whether that is necessarily an issue, but it's certainly an area to look into.

Comment: @dyp Strict aliasing was my concern as well. At the same time, there *is* actually an object of type `float` at that address (as a subobject of the complete object of type `quantity`). So maybe strict aliasing is not violated thanks to that?

Comment: The point about aliasing rules is whether the compiler must be aware of it to prevent unsafe optimizations, AFAICT. So, even though the type pun is valid (not UB when interpreted back to the exact original type)  it might "shroud" the compiler's view and make it do unsafe optimizations. I'd really have to know more about the APIs involved. Maybe someone else will chip in

Comment: @Angew Hmm that's true. C++11[class.mem]p20 has an explicit exception for that case; in C++14 this has been formulated differently, but not with the intent of forbidding this use case. I'm not entirely sure about pointer arithmetic, though.